# Dotnet core + WeView2 + Windows Zoom

Tags: windows, .net-core, webview2, zoom-sdk

Hy,

I have a problem with windows zoom, I made a project with dotnet core and webview2, I tried some solutions I saw on the web but it didn't work, whenever you zoom in windows the program distorts and tries to enlarge the images, how do I disable this in the program?

I don't want the zoom to influence the system dimensions